# (Java NetBeans MVC) Javascript link file not working?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, model-view-controller

I am doing a project in NetBeans and I need to call some function in javascript from an external file. I am using `header.jsp` and `footer.jsp` and linked them to all my other webpages.

I tried this line in both files and I'm not getting any output : 
 
`<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ressources/js/script.js"></script>`

For testing purposes, my javascript file is only containing this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("hello!");
});
```

I am coming from Visual Studio C# so I'm not used to Java and NetBeans environment. What could I do wrong? Is my link not working?

Cause I also tried `<script src="/ressources/js/script.js"></script>`...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did your jsp file contains in header:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
```

If yes, please provide full prj directory screenshot and console log from chrome developer tools